# How is reductio ad absurdum unintuitive?

Tags: logic, intuition, axioms, constructive-mathematics

I am not asking about opinions here, I'm asking for the reasoning behind the decision of certain logics/frameworks, like e.g. Intuitionism, to not contain RAA as a valid rule of inference. There is an assumption behind my assertion that there even is such a reasoning; some things are self-evident and thus do not have any reasoning beyond (universal) opinion. Other statements simply seem intuitively true, but the assertion of their truth may produce sufficiently counter-intuitive implications that cancel out, in a way, the intuitiveness of the original statement.

As such, my understanding is this:

The difference between logics and frameworks allowing RAA, and those that don't, **is not** that they disagree on RAA being intuitive in and of itself. Rather, accepting RAA as valid produces results that some peope find too counter-intuitive. Shortly put, the disagreement lies in the implications of RAA.

**Question:**

What counter-intuitive implications is it that motivates the removal of RAA as a rule of inference?

**Meta:**

I understand if this Q is too philosophical for Math.SE, and I will move it if its reception indicates this is true.

Comment: [Intuitionism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic/#RejTerNonDat) rejects Excluded Middle and its classical equivalent: the reason is there. And see [Brouwer’s Development of Intuitionism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/brouwer/#Bro).

Comment: See also [Bishop’s Constructive Mathematics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mathematics-constructive/#BishConsMath).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I disagree with the premise that intuitionists reject RAA because of counter-intuitive consequences, not because RAA itself is unintuitive. I think most people who are philosophically committed to intuitionism would claim that RAA is unintuitive on its face.

I want to clarify something first. The following form of RAA is perfectly acceptable to the intuitionist: If we assume $P$ and derive a contradiction, then we conclude $\lnot P$. In fact, in intuitionistic logic, $\lnot P$ is usually taken to be an abbreviation for $P\to \bot$, and the canonical way to prove $P\to \bot$ is to assume $P$ and derive $\bot$.

Similarly, the following is acceptable to the intuitionist: If we assume $\lnot P$ and derive a contradiction, then we conclude $\lnot \lnot P$. This is just an instance of the version of RAA from the last paragraph.

What the intuitionist rejects is the following form of RAA: If we assume $\lnot P$ and derive a contradiction, then we conclude $P$. As you can see, the issue comes down to double negation elimination: in intuitionistic logic, we cannot conclude $P$ from $\lnot\lnot P$.

To understand why, it's helpful to interpret the assertion $P$ as meaning not "$P$ is true", but rather something like "I have a proof of $P$", or "I have verified $P$". In this reading, $\lnot P$ means "I have ruled out that I could every verify $P$", and $\lnot\lnot P$ means "I have ruled out that I could rule out verifying $P$".

If I assume $\lnot P$ and derive a contradiction, then I have ruled out the possibility that I could rule out verifying $P$. This is not the same as actually having a verification of $P$ in hand. And that's why intuitionists find RAA unintuitive.

Comment: [This article by Andrej Bauer](http://math.andrej.com/2010/03/29/proof-of-negation-and-proof-by-contradiction/) and [this one by Robert Harper](https://existentialtype.wordpress.com/2017/03/04/a-proof-by-contradiction-is-not-a-proof-that-derives-a-contradiction/) make very much the same point: when people are puzzled by the intuitionistic rejection if RAA, it's usually because they don't understand what is actually being rejected.

Comment: Of course, I understand now.

Comment: Question: According to the intuitionist, if we assume a conditional '(P→Q)' and derive '⊥' can we conclude 'P'?  If the intuitionist answers 'yes', then the intuitionist will logically need to accept classical logic if they have the deduction meta-theorem.  If the intuitionist answers 'no', what is the meaning of '→'?

Comment: @DougSpoonwood The intuitionist emphatically answers 'no': For example, in the special case when $Q$ is $\bot$, if we assume $(P\to \bot)$ and derive $\bot$, then we conclude $(P\to \bot)\to \bot$, which is $\lnot\lnot P$. To conclude $P$ would be to eliminate the double negation, and I explained in my answer why this is unacceptable.

Comment: The meaning of $P\to Q$ should be understood as something like "I have a procedure for turning an arbitrary verification of $P$ into a verification of $Q$". In the case $Q = \bot$, $\lnot P = (P\to \bot)$ then means "I have a procedure for turning an arbitrary verification of $P$ into a verification of $\bot$." Since there can be no verification of $\bot$, this procedure rules out ever having a verification of $P$, which is the reading of $\lnot P$ I gave in my answer.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood Your insight that intuitionistic logic must leave the simple truth table semantics of classical propositional logic behind is correct, of course.

Comment: @AlexKruckman If the intuitionist does not divide propositions into "true" or "false" but into "can be verified" and "cannot be verified" how does he then distinguish between true propositions that cannot be verified and propositions that lead to $\bot$ ?

Comment: @Max Intuitionists do not divide propositions in the dichotomous way you suggest. Instead, they observe that there are some propositions for which we have proofs in hand, and others for which we do not (yet). As we prove more things, this line shifts. If we have a proof of $\lnot P$ (i.e., $P\to\bot$), then we can be confident that we will never have a proof of $P$. But of course there may be some propositions $P$ such that we never manage to prove $P$ and we never manage to prove $\lnot P$. The intuitionist does not believe that either $P$ or $\lnot P$ must be "really true".

Answer (score 0):

Without the use of the falsum $\bot$, following [the textbook 'Foundations of logic and mathematics' by Nievergelt](https://blackwells.co.uk/bookshop/product/9781461266235?gC=f177369a3b&gclid=CjwKCAiAu9vwBRAEEiwAzvjq-wVtUr7LziqYd9U1KBsJb8jey9AePrF989otClfixkDlcT4GaPipVxoCzn8QAvD_BwE) as a reference, especially Sections 1.1 and 4.1., there are two different laws.

*Law of Reductio Ad Absurdum*:
$$(P \to Q) \to ((P \to \neg Q) \to \neg P),$$

*Converse Law of Contraposition*:
$$(\neg P \to \neg Q) \to (Q \to P),$$

The Law of Reductio Ad Absurdum, as stated above, is valid in Intuitionistic Logic. What However, the Converse Law of Contraposition is not provable over Intuitionistic Logic.

---

Appendix:

For the convenience of the reader, I write down the axioms of Intuitionistic Logic, as taken from Nievergelt's book. In his book, the axioms of Intuitionistic Logic are stated completely over the language $\{\neg, \to, \vee, \wedge\}$, with the symbol $\neg$ for negation, the symbol $\to$ for implication, the symbol $\vee$ for disjunction and the symbol $\wedge$ for conjunction. In this language, the use of a constant symbol $\bot$ for the falsum is avoided.

To give the details, let $CL^-$ be the system consists of the following two axiom schemas:

1. $P \to (Q \to P)$
2. $(P \to (Q \to R)) \to ((P \to Q) \to (P \to R))$

Let $T$ denote $CL^{-}$ together with the additional five axiom schemas:

3. $(P \wedge Q) \to P$
4. $(P \wedge Q) \to Q$
5. $P \to (Q \to (P \wedge Q)$
6. $P \to (P \vee Q)$
7. $Q \to (P \vee Q)$
8. $(P \to R) \to ((Q \to R) \to ((P\vee Q) \to R))$

Intuitionistic Logic (IL) is $T$ plus the *Special Law of Reductio Ad Absurdum* -- $$(P \to \neg P) \to \neg P$$
and also plus the *Law of Denial Of the Antecedent*
$$\neg P \to (P \to Q).$$

Comment: What's the point of avoiding $\bot$?

Comment: To use a smaller set of connectives.