# $A$ is consistent iff $\lnot A$ is not provable

Tags: logic, model-theory

I'm currently reading through Jech's *Set Theory* and in chapter 12, an introduction to Model Theory. In particular, the section on "Relative Consistency" contains the assertion

> The question of whether $A$ is consistent with $T$ is equivalent to the question of whether the negation of $A$ is provable in $T$ (provided $T$ is consistent); this is because $T+A$ is consistent if and only if $\lnot A$ is not provable in $T$.

I understand the forward direction of this claim: clearly $A$ is provable in $T+A$, so consistency guarantees $\lnot A$ is not. However, I'm having trouble with the backwards direction. Why does $\lnot A$ not being provable in $T$ guarantee that adding $A$ doesn't accidentally make $\lnot A$ provable (somehow) or some other contradiction occur? Intuitively speaking, it makes sense that adding $A$ as an axiom shouldn't make it any easier to prove $\lnot A$, but how can we be sure no pathological example exists?

Comment: If $T+A$ is inconsistent, [it proves everything](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion), including $\neg A$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are asking why if $T+A$ is inconsistent, then $T$ proves $\lnot A$. This is just the usual statement of the method of proof by contradiction.

Comment: Technically, this is proof of negation, not proof by contradiction.

Comment: @MarkSaving True! But in a classical logic context (in the presence of double negation elimination), I think it's common to call both principles "proof by contradiction". I'm confident the OP will know what I mean by this phrase - not so confident for "proof of negation". Anyway, thanks for pointing it out - this conflation can cause [confusion](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4420824/7062).

Answer (score 3):

If $T+A$ proves $\neg A$, then $T$ proves $A\Rightarrow\neg A$. But $A\Rightarrow\neg A$ is equivalent to $\neg A$.